# Extra line breaks added when editing with Edge

Tags: bug, editor, microsoft-edge

When editing questions or answers with Microsoft Edge, I see every line break doubled:

### Edit with Google Chrome (Version 87.0.4280.66):

[image: Edit with Chrome]

### Edit with Microsoft Edge (Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0):

[image: Edit with MS Edge]

Note that I can't even enable reader mode:
[image: Reader mode grayed out]

I guess it has to do with how browsers handle [CR-LF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation), but isn't there a valid way for every browser?
If so, would it be possible to implement it?

Comment: Edge *is* Chrome now, right? So I can't see why the behavior would be different. Line breaks are platform-specific, not browser-specific, anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray I think this question is about the old edge, not the chromium edge.

Comment: The blunt edge, not the sharp edge?

Comment: @CodyGray not the sharpest Edge in the shed.

Comment: I edited my question to include the versions, and I'm talking about "Google Chrome" vs "Microsoft Edge", both screenshots were made on the same computer

Comment: Edge 44 is a very old version. Support for Edge Legacy ends [March 9, 2021](https://www.ghacks.net/2020/08/18/microsoft-edge-classic-support-ends-on-march-9-2021/) (just a couple months away); might be time to move to the newer version.

Comment: According to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge#Spartan_release_history) on the Edge Wikipedia page (you'll need to unhide it to see), OP's version is still "old" Edge, that is, pre-chromium adoption. It's not the most current "old" Edge, but appears to still be considered maintained (at least for now).

Comment: The OP could be talking about versions released for Android and iOS, which would still be a version behind the latest stable, or the current stable version on Xbox One. Although I'm not sure Stack Overflow supports entering posts from game consoles :).

Comment: No, I'm talking about Windows 10 (but it's company's computer so not something I'm able to update myself)

Comment: Is it affected by the configuration? E.g., does "reading view" in Edge affect text input fields? See e.g. *"[How to Change Text Spacing in Microsoft Edge Reading View in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/114225-change-text-spacing-microsoft-edge-reading-view-windows-10-a.html)"* and *"[Change Reading View Text Spacing in Microsoft Edge](https://winaero.com/reading-view-text-spacing-microsoft-edge/)"* (I couldn't find anything on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) (way too many false positives for Microsoft Word due to the word "Edge")).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'll try on monday, but it is not just text *spacing*, there is an actual line break. I'll tell you asap

Comment: @PeterMortensen OK so I followed your links, but "Reader mode" isn't even available (the open book is grayed out)

Comment: [Reported on the global meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349613/extra-line-breaks-appear-in-editor-when-editing-a-post-in-microsoft-edge). Yes, SE still considers the legacy version of Edge to be supported. (By the way, this seems to be fixed in the new editor, which is rolled out on Teams and is planned to be rolled out on public Q&A.)